# How to add a flag (such as -g) to the whole project (created by someone else)?

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, makefile, automake

I have a library I am using (which is critical to my work) that I am suspecting may have a bug. Unfortunately, the owner of the library is not so responsive as to trying out my sample codes. I am about to try debugging it myself.

To be more honest, it's not just a library, it's a library plus a set of kernel modules and the crash happens at kernel level (pretty nasty) and indeed would be hard to spot for the owner of the code too.

Sometimes that I get lucky, I get a kernel oops, that if I could build his code with -g option, I can find which line the error occurs (which greatly help, since I have just started facing huge amounts of his code with pretty much no clue).

Now the GNUmakefiles of the project are built with automake (I believe). My question is **How can I tell `make` to add `-g` to `CFLAGS` throught the WHOLE build?**

I remember reading something along the lines of how to write Makefiles so that "external" options can be added etc, but I neither know whether these makefiles would be generated with that ability (which should because it's automake), or how those external options are given anyway!

I am guessing something like this:

```
make CFLAGS=-g
```

should do it, but honestly have no idea.

---

Edit: Note that, I am actually interested in the `-g` flag to be included when the kernel modules are being built. I cannot use try and error (for example with my command above) to see if works or not, as the kernel build just prints `[CC] ...` without showing any options!

Edit: Well actually I did try, but `gdb ./module.ko` still claims there are no debug symbols.

Comment: If things crash inside the kernel(module), chances are big (100%) that the error lies in the kernel module. (I am not a kernel hacker) Kernel debugging is different. Shortlist: Does the module load? does it perform parameter validation on the arguments it gets (either from the kernel or via syscalls / ioctls) ? Does it respect the memory barriers between kernel-space and user-space?

Comment: @wildplasser, I know that. I spent a week on my own kernel module before suspecting the other one (which is RTAI by the way). In the end, I came up with a very simple kernel module using only RTAI functions that shows the exact same behavior. So it really can't by my own module's fault.

Comment: I even don't know hat an RTAI module is, so I'm afraid I cannot help you. Chances seem big that most people start out by copying other modules. Add to the shortlist: races and locks (hint: test on a single core machine, though that won't avoid all possible races). Good luck.

Comment: This is a Linux kernel issue right?  I mean, you're trying to debug a loadable module, so I've added the requisite tag.

Comment: @JeremyP, my problem in particular, yes, but I am looking for a more generic answer. That is, I am trying to find a way to give options (perhaps through `EXTRA_CFLAGS`) to the top-level `make` and get the option throughout all the build.

Comment: If it's autotools project, then probably you can do something like CFLAGS="-g" ./configure. Then make.

Comment: @dbrank0, I didn't know you can put that before `./configure`! Thanks

Comment: If its a kernel module `EXTRA_CFLAGS = -g` in you `Makefile` will do the trick. You can check it out (seems to work for me). If you need a more verbose build message make use of `V` option say `make V=1`. You can find more info on make options in the README file I think

Comment: @another.anon.coward, of course. But I didn't want to edit Makefiles of 15 modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a `configure` script? If so, was it created by autoconf? (Probably.) Then you can do

```
./configure CFLAGS='-g -O0'
make clean
make
```

to rebuild the whole thing with debugging on and optimization off.

Otherwise, no-one can really help you unless you provide a relevant excerpt of the makefile.

Comment: There is a configure script. RTAI uses a configuration similar to the kernels, but once done it runs the configure script. I could find where it is called inside RTAI's own Makefile.